# React Native view being pushed up and height changes dynamically when keypad pops out

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am designing an app in React Native and the problem I am facing right now is when I try to type in the TextBox, the keypad comes up and it pushes up or out the view changing height dynamically of other views too. Please check the Before and After image below:

[image]

The Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import t from 'tcomb-form-native'; // 0.6.9
const Form = t.form.Form;

import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ToastAndroid
  } from 'react-native';

  import { RFPercentage, RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      parentSectionContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        backgroundColor: '#F1F0F2'
      },
      SignupFormParent: {
        marginTop: 100,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        height: '45%',
        width: '85%',
        borderRadius: 100,
        shadowColor: '#2AC062',
        shadowOpacity: 0.4,
        shadowOffset: { height: 10, width: 0 },
        shadowRadius: 20,
      },
    textMelow: {
        width: RFPercentage(10),
        fontSize: RFPercentage(2),
        fontWeight: "normal",
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        fontStyle: 'normal'
    },
    textBold: {
        width: RFPercentage(10),
        fontSize: RFPercentage(2),
        fontWeight: "bold",
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        fontStyle: 'normal'
    },
    btnContainer: {
        paddingTop: 8,
        width: '100%',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignContent: 'center'
    },
    signupBodyStyle: {
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: 0,
      width: '90%',
      marginBottom: 20,
    },
    signinSignupButtonsBtnsContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      alignItems: 'center',
      width: '100%'
    },
    signupButtonBodyStyle: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#8A56AC',
      borderRadius: 100,
      alignItems: 'center',
      padding: 25
    },
    signinSignupTextStyle: {
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      fontSize: 18,
    }
  });

  const User = t.struct({
    name: t.String,
    email: t.String,
    password: t.String,
    "Confirm Password": t.String,
    location: t.String
  });

  const SignupForm = (props) => {

    const options = {
        auto: 'placeholders',
      };

    return (
        <View style={styles.SignupFormParent}>
            <View style={{ paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20, marginTop: 80 }}>
                {/* <Text style={styles.text}>FORM</Text> */}
                <Form type={User} options={options}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  };

  const ContinueButton = (props) => {
    const { onPress, style } = props;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={style.bodyStyle}>
        <View
          style={style.buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={style.textStyle}>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }


  export default class SignUpView extends Component {

    // constructor(props) {

    // }

    fetch('${Config.IP}:${Config.PORT}/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: 'jayndoe@foobar.com',
          password: "jynd1234",
        }),
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
          JSON.stringify(responseJson),
          ToastAndroid.SHORT,
          ToastAndroid.CENTER,
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
          JSON.stringify(error),
          ToastAndroid.SHORT,
          ToastAndroid.CENTER,
        );
      })
    } 

    render() {
      return(
          <View style={styles.parentSectionContainer}>
              <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#8A56AC', height: '30%', borderBottomLeftRadius: 120 }}/>
              <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 50, width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', margin: 'auto' }}>
                <Text style={styles.textBold}>LOG IN</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textMelow}>SIGN UP</Text>
              </View>
              <SignupForm
                    title="SIGN UP USING INSTAGRAM"
                    onPress={() => {this.instagramSSO()}}
                    style={{formStyles: styles.formStyles}}
                  />
              <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <ContinueButton
                    title="CONTINUE"
                    style={{ bodyStyle: styles.signinBodyStyle, buttonStyle: styles.signinButtonBodyStyle, textStyle: styles.signinSignupTextStyle }}
                    onPress={() => Alert.alert('Please sign-in!!')}
                  />
              </View>
          </View>
        );
    }
  }
```

Appreciate any help in resolving this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the absolute positionning of your views,
I think you used it because you needed to put the white input wrapper on top of the purple one view. Maybe you could remove the absolute positionning and use negative paddingTop on the white wrapper instead ? I am not sure how to achieve this using good practices, but that could prevent the keyboardavoidingview to push your other components.